# Hyphenation rules for product shelf life

Tags: word-order, sentence, word-usage

Given this sentence:

> Studies confirm the longest product shelf life of 3 years.

How do I make it correct and clear?

The product has a set of shelf lives (it is a pharmaceutical product). Studies confirm the longest self life, and therefore all the others as well. The longest shelf life is 3 years.

Is some sort of hyphenation needed, like "longest product-shelf-life"?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean: I thought that each batch of a product was assigned a single shelf life. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shelf_life) mentions different advisory / warning notices; these for food being easily distinguishable: 'For food, shelf life is different from expiration date: the former refers to food quality, the latter to food safety. A product that has passed its shelf life might still be safe, but quality is no longer guaranteed.' For a pharmaceutical product, I would imagine that the shortest-term factor dictated shelf life. (Hyphenation advice secondary.)

Comment: I, too, have to admit I don't understand the question. But the one thing that *is* crystal clear to me is that hyphenating *product-shelf-life* does not help with anything here. Other than making you look like a German spy, that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REVISED ANSWER:

Initially I recommended rephrasing the original example's wording as

> Studies confirm that the product has a maximum shelf life of three years.

But as Edwin Ashworth suggests in his comments, treating "shelf life" as a something with a range of possible durations from "shortest [or minimum] shelf life" to "longest [or maximum] shelf life" seems inconsistent with the underlying idea of "shelf life" as a time period of predictable, inelastic duration. That notion of the term seems to be the one embedded in the definition of "shelf life" that Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary, Eleventh Edition (2003) provides:

> the period of time during which a material may be stored and remain suitable for use

Of course, the straightforward Merriam-Webster's definition of "shelf life" doesn't address a real-world complication: Because many materials are heat-, humidity-, or light-sensitive, "shelf life" doesn't (in many cases) apply equally to storage in a hot, humid, bright environment and to storage in a cool, dry, dark environment. To make a specified "shelf life" meaningful, a manufacturer may include storage instructions (such as "Store in a cool, dry place" or "Store at 45 degrees F or below" or "Store away from light"); but even so, storage conditions may vary across a range from "ideal or optimum" to "adequate or acceptable."

Thus, even when the manufacturer specifies storage conditions, a particular item's actual period of usability may be longer or shorter depending on how close to ideal the storage conditions are. And when specifying a "shelf life" for a particular material, the manufacturer may have in mind its shelf life under the minimum acceptable storage conditions, its shelf life under average or typical acceptable storage conditions, or its shelf life under optimum storage conditions (among other possibilities). Since the OP's original example stresses "longest product shelf life," I suspect that the manufacturer here has in mind something like "shelf life under optimum storage conditions." That leads to the following revision of my original recommended rephrasing:

> Studies confirm that the product has a shelf life of three years under optimum storage conditions.

As I noted in my original answer, another aspect of the original example's wording deserves attention: The word confirm is appropriate only if the product's maker had already independently established that the shelf life in question was three years. In the absence of any such prior determination, the studies cited in the sentence are "finding," "ascertaining," or "determining" the shelf life under optimum conditions, not "confirming" it. In that case, the following wording would be more accurate:

> Studies have found that the product has a shelf life of three years under optimum storage conditions.

Comment: 'The maximum shelf life' is not a term I've ever come across. Products have **a** shelf life. If subsequent testing shows that the figure claimed was unsound, the figure is revised. This gives a new figure for the shelf life. The old figure is ditched. A product cannot have 'a set of shelf lives'.

Comment: Hi, Edwin Ashworth. I think you're right—"shelf life" is already expressed as a maximum period of usability and doesn't work well with comparative modifiers. I suspect that the OP's original wording used "longest" as an implicit acknowledgment that, under less-than-ideal storage conditions (say, on the shelf of an uncooled, unheated tin-roofed storage shed in the Mojave Desert), the product would have a shorter shelf life than three years. But it would be better to refer to the maximum period as the "shelf life under optimum conditions" than as the "longest [or "maximum"] shelf life."

Comment: Consonant with Edwin Ashworth's just criticism (above), I would change my final "more-accurate wording" to "Studies have found that under optimum conditions the product has a shelf life of three years." My first rephrasing of the sentence and my paragraph of discussion prior to that example are similarly flawed. This weekend, I'll revisit the answer in hopes of putting it to rights.

Comment: Thank you for your very complete discussion of the problem Sven, it has given me much new insight. Also, a thank you to everyone who commented.